# PHP: how to decode a string having "=20" and "=A0"

Tags: php, laravel-5, encoding, imap

I am using IMAP API to getting the emails from the gmail. But some email subjects are encoded like

```
=?utf-8?Q?We=20aren=27t=20fooling=20around=3A=20Up=20to=2050%=20off=20on=20Polo=27s=2C=20Swimwear=2C=20Jeans=20&=20More?=
```

I am not getting in which format it is encoded and how to decode it. The actual email subject is

```
We aren't fooling around: Up to 50% off on Polo's, Swimwear, Jeans & More
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: ^ in addition, you could use [`quoted_printable_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) function in PHP. it might work on your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP predefine function

> iconv_mime_decode()

```
<?php
   $str = "=?utf-8?Q?We=20aren=27t=20fooling=20around=3A=20Up=20to=2050%=20off=20on=20Polo=27s=2C=20Swimwear=2C=20Jeans=20&=20More?=";
    echo iconv_mime_decode($str);
```

Comment: It's not decoding properly

Comment: Is "=?utf-8?Q?" common to every string?

Comment: then you can use iconv_mime_decode_headers($str); but it will give you an array

Comment: Achieved check my solution

Answer (score 2):

Use [quoted_printable_decode — Convert a quoted-printable string to an 8 bit string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) function

```
$str = "=?utf-8?Q?We=20aren=27t=20fooling=20around=3A=20Up=20to=2050%=20off=20on=20Polo=27s=2C=20Swimwear=2C=20Jeans=20&=20More?=";
echo quoted_printable_decode ( $str );
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/3HXrv)

Comment: It's not decoding properly